# Jain sip registration successful but the client is unreachable in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, jain-sip

I have an issue related to jain sip and asterisk. I am using jain sip for registration to asterisk and I can receive a valid response (200 OK) from asterisk when the REGISTER request is sent out. The problem I am facing is that when I check the sip accounts in my asterisk server (version 11) the account status is unreachable but I see the host and ALC port. It just remains unreachable.

The command I am using is `sip show peers`

UPDATE: Register request using jain sip:

```
REGISTER sip:634@10.0.0.***:5060 SIP/2.0
Call-ID: 2a4edd77a04edcf91a183fb5e6390ed4@10.0.7.162
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
From: <sip:634@10.0.0.***:5060>;tag=1536045124
To: <sip:6034@10.0.0.***:5060>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.7.***:6060;branch=z9hG4bK-393136-32de53e08f3695b7a99325e95a230fa0
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:634@10.0.7.***:6060>
Content-Length: 0
```

After authentication I receive OK response:

```
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.7.***:6060;branch=z9hG4bK-393136-a334443342b349bd19bad069fd993a24;received=10.0.7.***;rport=6060
From: <sip:634@10.0.0.***:5060>;tag=1536045124
To: <sip:634@10.0.0.***:5060>;tag=as30c38f55
Call-ID: 2a4edd77a04edcf91a183fb5e6390ed4@10.0.7.***
CSeq: 3 REGISTER
Server: Asterisk PBX 11.14.2
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH,MESSAGE
Supported: replaces,timer
Expires: 120
Contact: <sip:634@10.0.7.***:6060>;expires=120
Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 14:25:04 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

As soon as I list the peers in asterisk I see that the sip account is registered but the status is UNREACHABLE.

```
634/john.smith       10.0.7.***                               D  Yes        Yes            6060     UNREACHABLE
```

At the moment we are using sip ml for sip registration to the server and it is working fine. Here is the request with sipML. I believe it has to be exactly the same as the jain sip request.

REGISTER request (working) using sipML

```
REGISTER sip:10.0.0.*** SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WS df7jal23ls0d.invalid;branch=z9hG4bKAGhrtV71dw2wnIemLhXuPFxn5UuT9VwB;rport
From: <sip:634@10.0.0.***>;tag=v4etua1Iu8gtHEy5zvdo
To: <sip:634@10.0.0.***>
Contact: "undefined"<sip:634@df7jal23ls0d.invalid;rtcweb-breaker=no;transport=ws>;expires=100;click2call=yes
Call-ID: 7e07cea7-3ee6-ce43-c463-7398e2a01e86
CSeq: 49416 REGISTER
Content-Length: 0
Route: <sip:10.0.0.***:5060;lr;sipml5-outbound;transport=udp>
Max-Forwards: 70
Authorization: Digest username="634",realm="asterisk",nonce="4c006498",uri="sip:10.0.0.***",response="467b2cc9e1f94b1c24fc5257692a2eb9",algorithm=MD5
User-Agent: IM-client/OMA1.0 sipML5-v1.0.0.0
Supported: path
```

(Note: IP addresses are hidden with asterisks!)

Thank you!
L

Comment: You should show the REGISTER request. The Contact header in there is key. In any case either the IP is unreachable or the transport is wrong somehow.

Comment: REGISTER request added to the post. Thank you!

Comment: Well, websocket is totally different transport, you need to check UDP connectivity. Try to set your Contact: <sip:10.0.7.***:6060;transport=udp> and make sure this 10.... IP is reachable.

Comment: Please check firewall and NAT settings.

Comment: hello
Do you mean the nat option in the users.conf file in asterisk?
It is set on `nat=yes`